# junit to test a method calling webservice

Tags: junit, mockito, webservice-client

I am newbie to junit.
 I need to do junit for the following method.  kindly guide me

```
   public boolean binlist(params hpproxy, calendarparam cpxproxy)

      {

       Getbinresponse binresponse;
       cpproxy.setid(hpproxy.getId());
       binresponse= cpproxy.getBinlist(); // resturns a list calling webservice
     if (binresponse.size>0)
      {
      result=true;
            }
         else
         {
          result=false;
         }   
      return result;      
         }
```

I have tried to test the binlist method using mock object.

```
    class testbin
     {
    @test
     public void testbinlist()
      {
          Testbin mocktestbin=mock(testbin.class);
      calendarproxy cpproxy=mock(calendarproxy.class);
      params hpproxy= mock(cparams.class);
        hpproxy.setId("123");
         stub(cpproxy.getBinList()).toReturn(gettestbins()) // mocked getbinlist()
        boolen result= mocktestbin.binlist();
          assertTrue(result);


        }

     }
```

how to test the webservice inside a method?

Comment: Please just do `return binresponse.size > 0;` instead of all those if else etc. It just reads a lot nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are pretty spot on in your test.  I think you do not need to mock the Testbin since that is the class under test.  Just create a mock of the calendarproxy that is being passed on as an argument.

So your test method to test bin would look something like what is below.

```
class testbin
{
    @test
    public void testbinlist()
    {
        Testbin mocktestbin= new Testbin();
        calendarproxy cpproxy=mock(calendarproxy.class);
        params hpproxy= mock(cparams.class);
        hpproxy.setId("123");
        when(cpproxy.getBinList()).thenReturn(gettestbins()); // mocked getbinlist()
        boolen result= mocktestbin.binlist(hpproxy,cpproxy);
        assertTrue(result);
    }
}
```